# Vulkan: validation layer: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-GeneralParameterError-UnrecognizedValue ]

Tags: validation, vulkan

I am trying to program the "Graphic Hello World Program" in Vulkan which has the goal to  draw a Triangle on the screen.

I am following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lr93-_cC8v4).

I am getting two types of Errors.

The first Error is:

```
validation layer: loaderAddLayerProperties: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.198.1\Bin\VkLayer_api_dump.json invalid layer manifest file version 1.2.0.  May cause errors.
validation layer: loaderAddLayerProperties: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.198.1\Bin\VkLayer_device_simulation.json invalid layer manifest file version 1.2.0.  May cause errors.
validation layer: loaderAddLayerProperties: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.198.1\Bin\VkLayer_gfxreconstruct.json invalid layer manifest file version 1.2.0.  May cause errors.
validation layer: loaderAddLayerProperties: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.198.1\Bin\VkLayer_khronos_synchronization2.json invalid layer manifest file version 1.2.0.  May cause errors.
validation layer: loaderAddLayerProperties: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.198.1\Bin\VkLayer_khronos_validation.json invalid layer manifest file version 1.2.0.  May cause errors.
validation layer: loaderAddLayerProperties: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.198.1\Bin\VkLayer_screenshot.json invalid layer manifest file version 1.2.0.  May cause errors.
```

which I could find in a post on stackoverflow  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215270/how-to-make-vk-layer-khronos-validation-available)
but I checked everything the solution is suggesting and the Error is still there.

The second Error is:

```
validation layer: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-GeneralParameterError-UnrecognizedValue ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xbe6eff91 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].blendEnable (-858993460) is neither VK_TRUE nor VK_FALSE. Applications MUST not pass any other values than VK_TRUE or VK_FALSE into a Vulkan implementation where a VkBool32 is expected.
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-srcColorBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xeb9e690 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].srcColorBlendFactor (-858993460) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: srcColorBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-srcColorBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstColorBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x8db942fe | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].dstColorBlendFactor (-858993460) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: dstColorBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstColorBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorBlendOp-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x7978ef4f | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].colorBlendOp (-858993460) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendOp enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: colorBlendOp must be a valid VkBlendOp value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorBlendOp-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-srcAlphaBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x4a7f8ed8 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].srcAlphaBlendFactor (-453845144) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: srcAlphaBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-srcAlphaBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstAlphaBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x53ab1c8f | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].dstAlphaBlendFactor (569) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: dstAlphaBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstAlphaBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-alphaBlendOp-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x48f9f9b | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].alphaBlendOp (-1467165950) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendOp enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: alphaBlendOp must be a valid VkBlendOp value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-alphaBlendOp-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorWriteMask-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x239e0488218, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xb8f9c032 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].colorWriteMask contains flag bits that are not recognized members of VkColorComponentFlagBits The Vulkan spec states: colorWriteMask must be a valid combination of VkColorComponentFlagBits values (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.198.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorWriteMask-parameter)
failed to submit draw command buffer!
```

I found a post on reddit which describes a similar problem [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/my890w/validation_layer_error_colorblendfactor_not_in/gvti1t6/) but the post isnt solved.

The `failed to submit draw command buffer!` message is thrown by a `std::runtime_error` caused by a `false` returnvalue of

```
vkQueueSubmit(device.graphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame])
```

Some additional information which my program prints out between this two Error Messages:

```
available extensions:
        VK_KHR_device_group_creation
        VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities
        VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities
        VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities
        VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2
        VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
        VK_KHR_surface
        VK_KHR_surface_protected_capabilities
        VK_KHR_win32_surface
        VK_EXT_debug_report
        VK_EXT_debug_utils
        VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace
        VK_NV_external_memory_capabilities
required extensions:
        VK_KHR_surface
        VK_KHR_win32_surface
        VK_EXT_debug_utils
Device count: 1
physical device: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER
Present mode: Mailbox
```

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

First error(s) is normal if your driver's Loader is old. It should be benign. See "Known Issues" in the [documentation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.198.1/windows/release_notes.html).

The second error(s) seems to be caused by `pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0]` member not existing in your code or being uninitialized.

The third error is probably a result of the second error (failing to create or creating an invalid Pipeline).

Comment: thank you now I understand the first error. The second Error I still dont understand because I am 100% sure that I initialize this structure. Because of this I linked the reddit post, it is the only discussion about this kind of error I found.

Comment: @Robin Validation layers do not tend to be wrong on this. Check also whether you are making a use-after-destroy. E.g. the layers see `-858993460` for the value of `blendEnable`. I think it is unlikely it is wrong on this or many would complain. Otherwisely, you can post your whole code here and we will figure it out one way or another...