# What can be the cause for pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0] values being out of bound / not VKBool32 errors

Tags: c++, graphics, game-engine, vulkan

I was new to Vulkan and was following youtube turtorials. So sorry if this problem is actually stupid. I received the following validation errors when I try to create a vulkan render pipeline.

```
validation layer: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-GeneralParameterError-UnrecognizedValue ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xbe6eff91 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].blendEnable (424) is neither VK_TRUE nor VK_FALSE. Applications MUST not pass any other values than VK_TRUE or VK_FALSE into a Vulkan implementation where a VkBool32 is expected.
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstColorBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x8db942fe | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].dstColorBlendFactor (-858993460) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: dstColorBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.170.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstColorBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorBlendOp-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x7978ef4f | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].colorBlendOp (-858993460) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendOp enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: colorBlendOp must be a valid VkBlendOp value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.170.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorBlendOp-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-srcAlphaBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x4a7f8ed8 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].srcAlphaBlendFactor (403017032) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: srcAlphaBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.170.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-srcAlphaBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstAlphaBlendFactor-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x53ab1c8f | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].dstAlphaBlendFactor (501) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendFactor enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: dstAlphaBlendFactor must be a valid VkBlendFactor value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.170.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-dstAlphaBlendFactor-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-alphaBlendOp-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x48f9f9b | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].alphaBlendOp (1741817829) does not fall within the begin..end range of the core VkBlendOp enumeration tokens and is not an extension added token. The Vulkan spec states: alphaBlendOp must be a valid VkBlendOp value (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.170.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-alphaBlendOp-parameter)
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorWriteMask-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x1f5132b26f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xb8f9c032 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: value of pCreateInfos[0].pColorBlendState->pAttachments[0].colorWriteMask contains flag bits that are not recognized members of VkColorComponentFlagBits The Vulkan spec states: colorWriteMask must be a valid combination of VkColorComponentFlagBits values (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.170.0/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState-colorWriteMask-parameter)
```

For me, it seems like I haven't initialize the ColorBlendStates parameters in the Pipeline Create Info. However, I do think I did initialize these values in my following code:

```
PipelineCfgInfo VulkanPipeline::DefaultPipelineConfigInfo(uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
{
    PipelineCfgInfo configInfo{};

    ...Initializations of other parameters...

    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_FALSE;
    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD; 
    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    configInfo.colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD; 

    ...Initializations of other parameters...

    return configInfo;
}
```

Btw, all other parameters were initialized successfully as they dont report an error message. The problem only occurred on the colorBlendAttachment parameters.

The PipelineCfgInfo struct is defined as below:

```
struct PipelineCfgInfo
{
    VkViewport viewport;
    VkRect2D scissor;
    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssemblyInfo;
    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizationInfo;
    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampleInfo;
    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment;
    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlendInfo;
    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencilInfo;
    VkPipelineLayout pipelineLayout = nullptr;
    VkRenderPass renderPass = nullptr;
    uint32_t subpass = 0;
};
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like you are using uninitialized memory - the values look random. Need to see a more complete example of how the structure is passed into the API.

Comment: Seems same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686831/vulkan-validation-layer-validation-error-unassigned-generalparametererror-u/70743151#70743151

Comment: I checked my code and found it is a life span issue with the PipelineCfgInfo struct. The memory is already freed before it is passed in to the API. Thank you for your help, have a good day.